# SQL: how to do an IF check for data range parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, sql-server-2012

I am writing a stored procedure that takes in 4 parameters: confirmation_number, payment_amount, start_range, end_range.

The parameters are optional, so I am doing a check in this fashion for the confirmation_number, and the payment_amount parameters:

```
IF (@s_Confirmation_Number IS NOT NULL) 
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND pd.TransactionNumber = @s_Confirmation_Number'

IF (@d_Payment_Amount IS NOT NULL) 
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND pd.PaymentAmount = @d_Payment_Amount'
```

I would like to ask for help because I am not sure what is the best method to check for the date range parameters.

If someone could give me en example, or several on how this is best achieved it would be great.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE** - after receiving some great help -.

This is what I have so far, I am following scsimon recommendation, but I am not sure about the dates, I got the idea from another post I found and some playing around with it. Would you care looking at it and tell me what you all think?

Many thanks.

```
    @s_Confirmation_Number  NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
,   @d_Payment_Amount       DECIMAL(18, 2) = NULL
,   @d_Start_Range          DATE = NULL
,   @d_End_Range            DATE = NULL
...
....

WHERE
    ph.SourceType = @s_Source_Type
    AND ((pd.TransConfirmID = @s_Confirmation_Number) OR @s_Confirmation_Number IS NULL)            
    AND ((pd.PaymentAmount = @d_Payment_Amount) OR @d_Payment_Amount IS NULL)
    AND (((NULLIF(@d_Start_Range, '') IS NULL) OR CAST(pd.CreatedDate AS DATE) >= @d_Start_Range)
    AND ((NULLIF(@d_End_Range, '') IS NULL) OR CAST(pd.CreatedDate AS DATE) <= @d_End_Range))
```

(The parameter sourceType is a hard-coded value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a *catch all* or *kitchen sink* query. It is usually written as such:

```
create procedure myProc
   (@Payment_Amount int = null     
   ,@Confirmation_Number  = null
   ,@start_range datetime
   ,@end_range datetime)

as

select ...
from ...
where 
    (pd.TransactionNumber = @Confirmation_Number or @Confirmation_Number is null)
and (pd.PaymentAmount = @Payment_Amount or @Payment_Amount is null)
```

The `NULL` on the two parameters gives them a default of `NULL` and makes them "optional". The `WHERE` clause evaluates this to only return rows where your user input matches the column value, or all rows when no user input was supplied (i.e. parameter `IS NULL`). **You can use this with the date parameters as well**. Just pay close attention to your parentheses. They matter **a lot** here because we are mixing `and` and `or` logic.

[Aaron Bertrand has blogged extensively on this.](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this

```
 WHERE 
    COALESCE(@s_Confirmation_Number,pd.TransactionNumber) = pd.TransactionNumber AND
    COALESCE(@d_Payment_Amount,pd.PaymentAmount) = pd.PaymentAmount
```

If we have a value for each of these parameters then it will check against the filter value otherwise it will always match the filter value if the parameter is null.

I've found that using COALESCE is faster and clearer than IF control statements or using OR in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *faster*? Just wondering if the compiler treats it differently than OR

Comment: @scsimon -- I believe the compilers are optimized to perform COALESCE faster than IF.  Only based on experience and I don't have a lot of knowledge of compiler design for SQL -- it would vary by internal architecture of course.  But it makes sense -- NULL handling is an important part of how SQL works so they would want to optimize it as op. to generic control statements.  CASE is the slowest -- that is why two of them is slower than an AND (as another answer).

Answer (score 1):

There is another way.
But I tested and realized that a [scsimon query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876157/5965412) is faster than mine.

```
AND (CASE 
    WHEN @Confirmation_Number is not null 
        THEN (CASE 
            WHEN pd.TransactionNumber = @Confirmation_Number 
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END)
    ELSE 1
END = 1)
```

Comment: a simple COALESCE or AND works much better than nested CASE statements.